# How to assign an ID to a group of variables

Tags: sas

I have a panel dataset and need to create an ID for groups of variables based on unique combination of (Year, LoadPort, DischargePort). There are other variables I would like to retain in the dataset but aren't needed to identify the group. For example:

```
Year LoadPort  DischargePort ID
2007 ARZEW     LOOP TERMINAL 1
2008 ARZEW     LOOP TERMINAL 1
2011 RAS TANURA ZHONGSHAN    2
2010 RAS TANURA ZHONGSHAN    2
```

I need to create the last column. This is what I have tried but it gives me nonsense results:

```
proc sort data=data.benchmark5;
by loadport dischargeport year;
run;

data data.benchmark6;
   set data.benchmark5;
   retain ID;
   by loadport dischargeport year;
   if first.year then ID = 0;
   ID = ID + 1;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the ID as your sample shows.

```
data data.benchmark6;
 set data.benchmark5;
  if loadport^=lag(loadport) or DischargePort^=lag(DischargePort) then ID+1;
    else ID+0;
 run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close; just increment your ID variable only on first.year:

```
data data.benchmark6;
   set data.benchmark5;
      by loadport dischargeport year;
   retain ID 0;
   if first.year then ID = ID + 1;
run;
```

Comment: `if first.year then` should be `if first.year and first.loadport and first.dischargeport then`.

Comment: @RobbieLiu I don't think so. The OP asked for unique combinations of all three variables. However, the example does not match that statement, so perhaps it should be `if first.dischargeport`.

Comment: I think OP may have made a mistake describing it since the sample given is based on two columns. Maybe you are right.