# SAS Dataset - Assign incremental value for each change in variable - sort by timestamp

Tags: sorting, sas

Similar to

[How to assign an ID to a group of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651609/how-to-assign-an-id-to-a-group-of-variables)

My dataset is sorted by ID, then timestamp. I need to create an 'order' variable, incrementing on each change in say Status, but my sort must remain time stamp, so I think I am correct in suggesting that by BY (group) will not work. The order field below illustrates what I seek...

```
ID   Status  Timestamp  Order  
188    3     12:15      1  
188    4     12:45      2  
188    4     13:10      2  
188    3     14:20      3  
189   10     11:00      1  
189   11     13:00      2  
189   10     13:30      3  
189   10     13:35      3
```

The first and second '3's are separate, likewise the first and subsequent '10's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, it is very similar to that other question. The trick here is to set the order of the first observation in each by group to zero.

```
data temp;
    input ID $ Status $ Timestamp $;
    datalines;
    188 3 12:15
    188 4 12:45
    188 4 13:10
    188 3 14:20
    189 10 11:00
    189 11 13:00
    189 10 13:30
    189 10 13:35
    ;
run;

data temp2;
    set temp;
    by id;
        if first.id then order = 0;
        if status ~= lag(status) then order + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Fantastic!! ...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NOTSORTED` option to have SAS automatically set the `FIRST.STATUS` flag for you.

```
 data want ;
   set have ;
   by id status notsorted;
   if first.id then order=0;
   order + first.status;
 run;
```